# How to save values of one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have tables that implements a one-to-many relationship: 1 Recipe = many Ingredients.

Updating values in the `Recipe` table works fine, but when I update or add a new `Ingredient`, it is not begin saved.

These are my models:

```
public partial class Recipe
{
    public Recipe()
    {
        RecipeIngredients = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string RecipeDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string TutorialLink { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string ImageFileName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
}

public partial class RecipeIngredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>()
            .HasMany(e => e.RecipeIngredients)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Recipe)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Here is the code in the controller:

```
using (RecipeEntityDataModel dbContext = new RecipeEntityDataModel())
{
    dbContext.Recipes.AddOrUpdate(recipe);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

What am I missing? Or is there anything wrong with the implementation?

I have tried updating the navigation property but it didn't work.

I would like to add/edit values to the table that has a relationship to the `Recipe` table.

Comment: What is the object data in recipe you have. The child data also should be binding over there.

Comment: In the above sample code, where you are adding/updating RecipeIngredient object?

Comment: What's the version of asp.net core you have used?

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't save data, EF and ADO.NET do. What version of Entity Framework are you using? There's no `AddOrUpdate` in EF Core. Are you using Entity Framework 6.x?

Comment: `AddOrUpdate` will mark both `recipe` and all related entities as either new or modified, depending on whether their PK properties have a default value or not. It doesn't save anything. All changes are cached and saved in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. What does `recipe.RecipeIngredients` contain? Does it have any items in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use for add or update that way

```
// Check for Recipe if exist in the database
var recipe = dbContext.Recipes
    .Include(x => x.RecipeIngredients)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);


// Create new RecipeIngredient
var recipeIngredient = new RecipeIngredient
{
   Description = "Ingredient name",
}


if (recipe != null)
{
    recipe.RecipeIngredients.Add(recipeIngredient);
}
else
{
    var newRecipe = new Recipe
    {
        RecipeName = "Recipe Name",
        // Set all props you need,
        RecipeIngredients = new List<RecipeIngredient> { recipeIngredient },
    }

    dbContext.Add(newRecipe);
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But in my opinion the relation should be many to many because it is assumed that one ingredient can be contained in more than one recipe

Comment: `AddAsync` isn't needed and the OP seems to be using Entity Framework, not EF Core. There's no `AddOrUpdate` in EF Core. `Update` behaves the way `AddOrUpdate` did

Comment: Correct, just a habit of writing AddAsync

Comment: `Add` is an in-memory operation while `AddAsync` goes to the database to retrieve a new database-generated key value. It doesn't actually insert a new object, it retrieves a new ID value. That's only needed if you use a special type of key generator, eg SequenceHiLo, which retrieves a batch of sequential values from the database for future use by the client.